# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel

'i cant updata data error The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. i dont know i need help thank you  '
   'this is my controller'

```
  public function edit($id){

        $slider = DB::table('header_sliders')->find($id);

        return   view('posts.edit',['header'=>$slider]);

       }

       public function update(Request $request,$id){

        $slider = DB::table('header_sliders')->find($id);

        $header->text = $request->input('text');
        $header->imgName = $request->input('imgName');

        $header->update();

        return  redirect('admin/index',['header'=>$slider]);

       }
```

'this is my view'

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <form action="{{url('admin/edit/'.$header->id)}}"  method="POST" >
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{method_field('PUT')}}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Mətn</label>
        <input type="text" name="text" class="form-control"  aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="{{$header->text}}">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Şəkil</label>
        <input type="file" name="imgName" class="form-control"  value="{{$header->imgName}}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
    </div>
    <a href ="{{url('admin/index')}}"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Dəyiş</button></a>

    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share your route `web.php` file?

Comment: yes Route::put('admin/index, Admin\HeaderSlidercontroller@update');

Comment: You're missing quotes, you need `Route::put('admin/index', 'Admin\HeaderSlidercontroller@update');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route `admin/edit/` is only accepting GET, you should change it to:

```
Route::put('admin/edit/{header}', 'Admin\HeaderSlidercontroller@update');
```

And remove the `a` tag:

```
<a href ="{{url('admin/index')}}">
```

Comment: i am change,  Creating default object from empty value    $header->text = $request->input('text');

Comment: you are not declaring `$header` in your controller, did you mean `$slider`?

Comment: okey code working but one problem) Call to undefined method stdClass::update()

Comment: Replace all your headers by sliders in your controller code

Comment: please remove the `a` tag as shown in the updated answer

Answer (score 12):

**Running command helped me**

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

better you check the route exists or not, if not then you should create it

`php artisan route:list`

based on your view theres conflicted route

```
 <form action="{{url('admin/edit/'.$header->id)}}"  method="POST" >
 {{method_field('PUT')}}`
```

make sure what you need to do, **PUT** or **POST** but not both

this route `Route::put('admin/index, Admin\HeaderSlidercontroller@update');` not have an argument, so you don't need to put an argument to html form

`<form action="{{url('admin/index')}}"  method="PUT" >`

and remove this `a` tag
`<a href ="{{url('admin/index')}}"> ...`

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding your trying to submit a form on the `get` method route which is not valid:

you need to change your route in your form as per below:

```
<form action="{{url('admin/update/'.$header->id)}}"  method="POST">
```